# How do I know my network traffic go through Asia-America Gateway (AAG) Cable System?

Tags: routing, internet, wan, isp

I have leased many internet links from many ISP with the requirement: "do not route my traffic to  Asia-America Gateway (AAG) Cable System".

How can I check that the ISPs are compliant with my requirement?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way of knowing this for certain.  A cable system in and of itself is a Layer 1 connection and does not report any information about itself (even to a traceroute).

You may be able to infer connectivity from the name resolution of hops along your traceroute, but you could never prove this (there may be multiple cable systems between the two end cities) without intimate knowledge of your service provider's network.

Take for example the following traceroute - it crosses 3 continents (AU, US, UK):

```
traceroute to www.fluent.co.uk (185.17.180.72), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
1  172.16.10.254 (172.16.10.254)  3.108 ms  2.145 ms  2.026 ms
2  lo0.bras2.bne3.on.ii.net (150.101.32.110)  24.534 ms  24.116 ms  24.078 ms
3  po10.bras2.bne3.on.ii.net (150.101.35.84)  24.251 ms  24.306 ms  24.967 ms
4  ae19.cr1.bne4.on.ii.net (150.101.40.132)  197.765 ms  196.924 ms  196.227 ms
5  ae6.br1.syd7.on.ii.net (150.101.33.76)  40.401 ms  41.589 ms  41.875 ms
6  te0-2-0-3.br2.sjc2.on.ii.net (203.16.213.158)  196.590 ms  197.375 ms  198.419 ms
7  sjo-b21-link.telia.net (62.115.51.153)  199.575 ms  196.472 ms
   sjo-b21-link.telia.net (62.115.33.97)  198.420 ms
8  palo-b1-link.telia.net (80.91.253.2)  201.334 ms
   palo-b1-link.telia.net (62.115.118.214)  220.833 ms
   palo-b1-link.telia.net (80.91.253.0)  196.249 ms
9  tata-ic-309366-palo-b1.c.telia.net (213.248.75.182)  219.374 ms  217.245 ms  396.226 ms
10  if-ae-5-2.tcore2.sqn-san-jose.as6453.net (64.86.21.1)  614.560 ms  743.459 ms  614.462 ms
11  if-ae-1-2.tcore1.sqn-san-jose.as6453.net (63.243.205.1)  603.368 ms *  363.054 ms
12  if-ae-12-2.tcore1.nto-new-york.as6453.net (63.243.128.28)  374.578 ms  359.758 ms  362.822 ms
13  if-ae-7-2.tcore1.n0v-new-york.as6453.net (63.243.128.26)  355.214 ms  644.454 ms  354.952 ms
14  if-ae-5-2.thar1.njy-newark.as6453.net (66.198.70.81)  568.368 ms  361.586 ms  363.128 ms
15  if-ae-8-2.tcore1.ldn-london.as6453.net (66.198.70.174)  615.816 ms  355.035 ms  354.734 ms
16  if-ae-28-2.thar1.ly9-london.as6453.net (80.231.60.110)  646.951 ms  420.924 ms  362.560 ms
17  195.219.92.81 (195.219.92.81)  362.177 ms  363.939 ms  368.033 ms
18  te1-50-157.core-rs3.vt.nimbushosting.co.uk (80.249.107.162)  500.054 ms  613.970 ms  614.357 ms
19  holding-stenning.nh-serv.co.uk (185.17.180.72)  614.420 ms  613.925 ms  614.419 ms
```

From hop 5 to hop 6 I can infer that I crossed from Sydney to San Jose based on the DNS name associated with the router interface and the latency spike, but I have no guide as to whether I went direct via the Southern Cross Cable Network (SCCN) system, or via Guam over PPC1 and then AAG.

Also, if these are Internet links, traffic may cross AAG to get to you regardless (upstream provider may use AAG), so I'm not sure how you or your provider(s) could possibly enforce this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trace your route, and find the providers of the IPs that are shown.